# Editing Record in Access Database Not Functioning

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

When I try to edit a record in Access database I only hear peep tone and no changes can take effect. 
Another problem I have is: as soon as I sort records I am not allowed to change them after that.
(I am working with MS Access 2010)
Did anybody had a similar problems and resolved them?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry this is very unspecific. Where's the code which shows the problem. Are you using DAO-Recordsets.

have you enclosed the changes to a record in

dim rs as DAO.Recordset

rs.edit
  rs!FieldYouLikeToChange = 10
rs.update

Of does the code look like
DoCmd.RunSQL "Update myTable set whatever = " & someValue

or the like

We simply do not know.

Regards

Comment: hm... Please tell me where can I find the information you mentioned. (I am a beginner with Access...) Thanks!

Comment: Well there are really quite a few good Access books available. And one may believe it or not the Online help is quite well also. So maybe it would be worth so check out the online docs first and then get a book about access Programming. It's IMHO comparable easy to really get amazing things done in quite a short time...

Comment: Hi Friedrich!
I have taken a look at Access tutorial. In the tutorial is stated that it is possible to make changes in Queries as in Forms. However, that is exactly the problem I have - as soon as I try to edit something, I get peep tone. I could send you a query if that helps. Please let me know.

Comment: Of course can you change it. If you have a form the stuff in it can be edited of course. But in the case that you deactivate some elements. And the beep surely comes form somthing else. There are of course cases when you can't edit elements, but we can not know without the tables forms etc.